Duplicate Key Exception in MassTransit StateMachine with MongoDB
I'm new to MassTransit and I'm encountering an issue with my StateMachine when using MongoDB for persistence. My current version for both MassTransit and MassTransit.MongoDB is 8.2.2. I frequently receive a MongoDB.Driver.MongoWriteException related to a duplicate key error:
MongoDB.Driver.MongoWriteException: A write operation resulted in an error.
WriteError: {
    Category: "DuplicateKey",
    Code: 11000,
    Message: "E11000 duplicate key error collection: sagas.chat.states index: _id_ dup key: { _id: BinData(3, 0000154A12AC4202841C08DC79794DA5) }"
}. 

Here’s a simplified extract of my state machine and the corresponding consumer for the request:
State Machine:
public class ChatStateMachine : MassTransitStateMachine<ChatState>
{
    public ChatStateMachine()
    {
        InstanceState(x => x.CurrentState);
        Event(() => StartingEvent, x => x.CorrelateById(y => y.Message.SomeId));

        Request(() => SomeField, x => x.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

        Initially(
            Ignore(SomeField.Completed),
            When(StartingEvent)
                .Request(SomeField, x => new SomeFieldRequest
                {
                    SomeId = x.Saga.CorrelationId,
                    SomeDefinitionId = x.Saga.SomeDefinitionId,
                    FieldResults = x.Saga.FieldResults,
                    Fields = x.Saga.Fields
                })
                .TransitionTo(SomeFieldState));
    }

    public State SomeFieldState { get; private set; }
    public Event<StartChatConversationEvent> StartingEvent { get; private set; }
    public Request<ChatState, SomeFieldRequest, SomeFieldResponse> SomeField { get; private set; }
} 

SomeFieldConsumer:
public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<SomeFieldRequest> context)
{
    await context.RespondAsync(new SomeFieldResponse
    {
        SomeId = Guid.Empty,
        NextFieldId = null,
        Role = Role.Undefined
    });
} 

When I remove the line Ignore(NextFormField.Completed), the duplicate key exception doesn’t occur. I thought that using Ignore would just skip over certain events without changing the state of the saga.
Also, I found that adding a delay with await Task.Delay(1000); in the consumer stops the exception too. I’m confused because I was under the impression that the state wouldn’t be saved until the whole transaction, including transitions, is done. I don't really understand how the consumer’s response affects this.
Does anyone know why this might be happening or what I’ve got wrong?

You shouldn't have an Ignore statement in Initially, the response is likely coming back before the transaction has been committed.

Thank you for the quick reply. If I can not have an Ignore statement in Initially, does that mean I need to slow down my request such that it can not come up before saving the saga state? I also noticed that when an ignore is triggered, the version number is being increased. Is that the normal behaviour or is my configuration wrong?
